# How to bind a ViewModel that has sub-viewmodel properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, html-helper

I am curious to know the best way to approach the following scenario:

```
public class LittleThingViewModel
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

public class BigThingViewModel
{
    public LittleThingViewModel little1 {get; set; }
    public LittleThingViewModel little2 {get; set; }
    public string propA {get; set; }
    public string propB {get; set; }
    public string propC {get; set; }
}
```

In the initial CREATE action of my controller, I populate two LittleThingViewModels, assign them to a new BigThingViewModel and pass it to the strongly-typed view.  I then use EditorFor to render edit controls for BigThing properties A, B, and C.

What is the best technique for automatically rendering the LittleThingViewModels to the form such that when I post back to my controller it auto-binds?  (My goal is to only display the Name and keep the other properties hidden)

```
public ActionResult Create(BigThingViewModel b)
```

I found that I could render A, B, and C properties in addition to each individual property of the two LittleThing sub-viewmodels and it successfully bind BigThingViewModel during POST:

```
Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.little1.Name)
Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.little1.Name)
Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.little1.Id)
Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.little1.Location)
```

Is there a technique that would allow me to render both labels and hidden elements automatically instead of having to do them each explicitly each time?

Something like:

```
Html.RenderFor(model=>model.little1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [partial view](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/638_Understanding_Partial_Views_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx) that is strongly typed to the LittleThingViewModel.

LittleThingView.ascx (partial view)

```
Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Name)
Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Name)
Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)
Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Location)
```

In main View

```
<%
Html.RenderPartial("LittleThingView",model.little1);
Html.RenderPartial("LittleThingView",model.little2);
%>
```

To make it look better you can make a collection for these objects in the big ViewModel. So if one of them is null or you need more than one, it wouldn't need any changes.

```
public class BigThingViewModel
{
    public List<LittleThingViewModel> littles=new List<LittleThingViewModel>();
    public string propA {get; set; }
    public string propB {get; set; }
    public string propC {get; set; }
}
```

And in the view:

```
<%
foreach(var littleThingViewModel in model.littles)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("LittleThingView",littleThingViewModel);
}
%>
```

Comment: I have a similar view model and I'm using a partial view to render it.  It's in a form though, and when my POST action is called on submit, the properties in my equivalent to LittleThingViewModel are not populated.  Do I need to implement a custom model binder for this?